# PowerShell - Get Win-Event of today

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am trying to get all the windows events of today

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName myComputer -FilterHashtable @{
  StartTime={[datetime]::Today.ToString('DD/MM/YY')}
  EndTime={[datetime]::Today.ToString('DD/MM/YY')}
}
```

I have a wrong dateTime format error.
What is the correct format ?

Comment: The correct format is _no format_. `StartTime` already accepts a `DateTime` value: `-FilterHashtable @{ StartTime = [datetime]::Today }` will give you all events from midnight today

Comment: See the examples of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass the date object. See [the docs for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.1#example-16--use-filterhashtable-to-get-events-from-the-application-log)

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName myComputer -FilterHashtable @{StartTime=[datetime]::Today}
```

Comment: Oh right it works fine ! I thought it did not work either because it does not accept  `EndTime=[datetime]::Today` ! Thanks